# How to verify that an API Request is coming from my Javascript on my Site?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, authorization

I have some JS on my website which requests Data from my own PHP API and the API request data from external APIs (Google, YT etc.)

How can my own PHP API can verify, that the request is from MY Javascript and not from someone else?

Comment: That's part of the job of Session Management. It's not very practical to give you all the details, or even the concepts, here. You should probably google "php session management" and learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to simply prevent people from accessing your API through JS on other sites you can just set the CORS header [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/256/setting-up-the-access-control-allow-origin-header) to your own domain.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your.domain.here");
```

Note that this doesn't mean people can't access your API through direct calls using software like Postman, python scripts etc.

If, for example, you want only yourself and/or specific users to be able to access the API you could look into php session management. This way you can create accounts which are allowed to access specific data on your API.

You could also use API keys to allow users to directly communicate with your API if needed.

Comment: If I use API Keys and then request the API via Javascript wouldn't it be possible to just read out the API Keys on the client site?

Comment: @thestartercoder Yes, you're right, API keys shouldn't be exposed in the frontend. Using them is probably something you should avoid if you only intend on requesting the data through the JS on your browser.

You could look at this https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php to manage users on your website and build on top of that to add verification to your API calls by passing a user's sessionid to the API for verification.